# How does "vec = [[0] * 9] * 9" work in Python?

Tags: python, matrix

I was trying to initialize a matrix in Python. I did this:

```
matrix = [[0] * 9] * 9
matrix[0][0] = 1
print(matrix[1][0])
```

This outputs **1**.

Can someone explain why this happens and how **[[0] * 9] * 9** works.

My guess is that all the vectors are pointers to the same vector instead of to different vectors, but I don't know why that happens and why **[0] * 9** doesn't have the same issue.

Comment: Your problem is exactly the same as the one in the dupe; the answers explain the cause fairly well. Don't feel bad; this bites every new Python programmer sooner or later.

Comment: You can also refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72501577/when-does-list-multiplication-create-multiple-copies-of-the-object-and-when-does/72501627#72501627